# How to hide the button after clicking in Android

Tags: java, android

The program is running well. The problem is that you have to click 2 times before you can hide it.

What if I want just one click and the play button disappears? Where is my code wrong.

**Layout:**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button111"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/play" />
```

**Java:**

```
 public void playSong(View v) {
        this.songIntent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
        this.songIntent.putExtra("song", "suara_" + randomResult);
        final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button111);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(SHARED_KEY_BUTTON_HIDE, true);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
        startService(this.songIntent);
    }
```

Comment: if you use a clicklistener then why `android:onClick="playSong"`?

Comment: i want playsong and hide button if user press the button

Comment: Since you've set `android:onClick="playSong` in the XML, the button will perform that method once you click on it. Within `playSong()` you're overriding its `OnClickListener`, so if you click on it a second time, this listener will be performed, which hides the button. Copy-pasting that code within the listener out into the `playSong` method should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code which handles the hiding out of the new `onClickListener` and put it right in the `playSong` method.

```
public void playSong(View v) {

    this.songIntent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
    this.songIntent.putExtra("song", "suara_" + randomResult);
    final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button111);

    myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(SHARED_KEY_BUTTON_HIDE, true);
    editor.apply();

    startService(this.songIntent);
}
```